# Check if a form is opened through a particular form/button in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I have made 2 different forms, 'Administrator' and 'Student' with an option of 'Password Change' and then created another form which ask for 'New password' from the user and which opens when user click on the 'Password Change' option in the 'Administrator' or 'Student' form.

I want to know if there is any way that i can check whether the 'New password' form is opened by clicking the link of 'Administrator' form or 'Student' form. If the 'New Password' form is opened by clicking the 'Password Change' link of Admin menu then update the password of Admin and if the 'New password' form is opened through Student form the update the password of Student.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would make two subclasses from `NewPassword` as the ammount of if clauses you would have to check what your property is could be immense

```
AdminNewPassword : NewPassword
StudentNewPassword : NewPassword
```

Then you can still have all your logic in new password, but whenever you need to handle things differently, they can go in the respective forms.

Then for an admin, you call  `new AdminNewPassword`.. Student - `StudentNewPassword`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is add a property to "New password" form with name of mode:

```
class NewPassword()
{
   ...
   public string Mode {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

before call ShowDialog method first set this property.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be the implementation of a public property on the new password form and set it from the opening form. Then you can check its contents from the new password form:

In new password form:

```
public string Opener;

if(Opener == "admin")
  // set admin password
else
  // set student password
```

In the other forms:

```
FrmNewPassword frmPasswd = new FrmNewPassword();
   frmPasswd.Opener = "admin"; // or frmPasswd = "student";
   frmPasswd.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a public property in the 'New Password' form and set it from which ever form you are opening it before opening the form. You can do it with either object or string or what ever type you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the admin and students are inherited from the same type you can simply pass the object in the constructor of the form as the base type. You will need the base class declared project level So if your base class is Person and you inherit 2 classes from that Admin and Student

In the calling form declare your user as either Admin or Student(Student s1) Then in your password form's constructor use something like this:

```
public New_Password_Form(Person User)
```

In your calling form to show this form include the user.

```
New_Password_Form npf = new New_Password_Form(s1);
npf.ShowDialog();
```

This gives the new password form access to all the  properties inherited from Person for that user, and the changes will be persistent.  Once the form closes you can save the new info according to the way you've already established.